# White screen after deploying react app on Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, vercel

I'm having an issue uploading the React app at Vercel, even everything runs smoothly at the end I see the white screen.
There is one error on console:

and
[image]

Any syntax mistakes or references I mistakenly added here in here? My build was successful but all I could see I blank page in my deployed site

```json
{
  "name": "query-react-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "ckeditor5-built-custom": "file:./ckeditor5-built-custom",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^33.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^4.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular": "^5.0.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.16",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "ckeditor5": "^33.0.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.11",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8196 start",
    "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8196 build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

App.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

import { AuthProvider } from './shared/context/authContext'

import Home from './user/pages/home'
import Navigation from './shared/components/Navigation/Header'
import styles from './index.scss'
import MainAuth from './user/pages/formElements/authentication/MainAuth'
import NewQuery from './query/pages/newQuery'
import AllQueries from './query/pages/AllQueries'
import Query from './query/pages/Query'
import Profile from './user/pages/Profile'
import EditQuery from './query/pages/editQuery/editQuery'
import EditProfile from './user/pages/formElements/EditProfile/editProfile'
import MainFooter from './shared/components/Footer/MainFooter'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Navigation />
          <main className={styles.main}>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} exact={true} />
              <Route path="/query" element={<NewQuery />} exact={true} />
              <Route
                path="/queries/:queryId"
                element={<Query />}
                exact={true}
              />
              <Route path="/queries" element={<AllQueries />} exact={true} />
              <Route path="/auth" element={<MainAuth />} exact={true} />
              <Route path="/users/:userId" element={<Profile />} exact={true} />
              <Route
                path="/:userId/edit"
                element={<EditProfile />}
                exact={true}
              />
              <Route
                path="/queries/:queryId/edit"
                element={<EditQuery />}
                exact={true}
              />
            </Routes>
            {/* <Navigate to="/" element={<Home />} /> */}
          </main>
          <footer>
            <MainFooter />
          </footer>
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Home.js**
I think error is in home.js It is fetching api from backend which is not hosted yet but it will throw error on console and there is no error
I am not sure

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import styles from './home.module.scss'
// import stylesVariable from '../../shared/SassVariables/variable.scss'
import Jumbotron from '../../shared/components/UIElements/Jumbotron'
import Card from '../../shared/components/UIElements/Card'
import axios from 'axios'

const Home = () => {
  const [totalQues, setTotalQues] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/queries').then(
      (response) => {
        if (response.data) setTotalQues(response.data.length)
      },
      (error) => console.log(error),
    )
  })

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Jumbotron height="fit-content" width="92%" curve="curve" stackOverFlow>
        <div className={styles.home__jumbotron2}>
          <Jumbotron
            height="fit-content"
            button="Join the community"
            to="/login"
            mainText="Join our Communtity"
            subText="Get the best answer to your technical questions, help others answer theirs"
            backgroundColor="lightsalmon"
          />
          <Jumbotron
            height="fit-content"
            button="Join the devps Community"
            to="/"
            mainText="Contribute to our code"
            subText="Improve the site perfornmace with contribute to our code via github"
            backgroundColor="rgb(150, 235, 150)"
          />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.jumbotron__text}>
          <h1> Yours every Doubt needs answer</h1>
        </div>

        <div>
          <ul className={styles.home__displayQues}>
            <li>
              <h3>Total Queries</h3> <p>{totalQues}</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h3>Pending Queries</h3> <p>{265}</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h3>Avg. response Time</h3> <p>30 min</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h3>active Users</h3>{' '}
              <p>{Math.floor((Math.random() + 1) * 15)}</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </Jumbotron>
      <div className={styles.home__card__div}>
        <Card className={styles.home__card}>
          <h1>A Thanks to our Contributer's</h1>
          <ul>
            <li>Tanuj Sharma</li>
          </ul>
        </Card>
        <Jumbotron
          height="fit-content"
          button="Read More"
          to="/"
          mainText="About Query-Point"
          subText=""
          backgroundColor="rgb(150, 235, 150)"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1 style={{ color: 'white', margin: '1rem' }}>Trending Tags</h1>
        <div className={styles.home__trend__card}>
          <ul>
            <li>#{'python'}</li>
            <li>#{'java'}</li>
            <li>#{'ReactJs'}</li>
            <li>#{'Spring-boot'}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: It would help if you could share the file contents of where the Routes are defined

Comment: Did you add the build output path in vercel?

Comment: No, I deployed whole project with default configuration

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this issue? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe make a "homepage": "vercel url here"
inside your package.json

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add "homepage" inside your package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage":"vercel url here" ,
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",...
```